# AdoQuery not working with SHOW: command

Tags: delphi

and I am tearing my hair out!!

Even something simple like this work:

```
procedure MyAdoQueryTest();
   const MYSQL_CONNECT_STRING='Driver={MySQL ODBC 5.1 Driver};Server=%s;Port=3306;Database=%s;User=%s;Password=%s;Option=3;';

   var   AdoConnection  : TADOConnection;
         ADOQuery : TADOQuery;
         Param    : TParameter;
begin
   AdoConnection := TADOConnection.Create(Nil);
   AdoConnection.ConnectionString := Format(MYSQL_CONNECT_STRING,['localhost',
                                                                  'mysql',
                                                              'root',
                                                              '']);
    AdoConnection.LoginPrompt := False;
    AdoConnection.Connected := True;

   ADOQuery := TADOQuery.Create(Nil);
   ADOQuery.Connection := AdoConnection;
   ADOQuery.Sql.Clear();
   ADOQuery.SQl.Add('SHOW :what_to_show');

   Param := ADOQuery.Parameters.ParamByName('what_to_show');
   Param.DataType := ftString;
   Param.Value := 'databases';

   ADOQuery.Prepared := true;
   ADOQuery.Active := True;
end;
```

(btw, do I really need to use the 'Param' variable and 3 statements, or can I just ` ADOQuery.Parameters.ParamByName('what_to_show').Value := 'databases';?)

Anyway, when I run it, I get an exception at `ADOQuery.SQl.Add('SHOW :what_to_show');` which says "Arguments are of the wrong type, are out of the acceptable range or are in conflict with one another".

What I am trying to do is to make 2 central functions: one which will accept and execute any SQL statement which will not return any data (such as INSERT INTO) and oen which will (such as SELECT).

I currently have these working with AdoConnection only, but am now trying to use AdoQuery because I want to parametrize my SQL statements to handle strings with quotes in them.

I can has halpz?

Comment: Just a guess, but I think AdoQuery was meant for the standard SQL statements only, like INSERT, SELECT and DELETE. You might want to try these before cracking on with SHOW, for which you may be stuck with AdoConnection... Wrt to the three statements: you should be able to do what you want, but you may have to move your AdoQuery.Prepared before setting the param values.

Comment: @Marjan, sorry you are way off, Params can only be used for values, not for other SQL-elements. This is a universal thing.

Comment: @johan, I think you misinterpreted my statement. I meant that you can do `ADOQuery.Parameters.ParamByName('what_to_show').Value := 'databases';` for parameters. I did not say that you could use parameters to support SHOW.

Comment: @Marjan, ok my bad. I was confused by your statement.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error is here:

```
ADOQuery.SQl.Add('SHOW :what_to_show');
```

The `:Param` can only be used for values, not for dynamic column/keyword/table/database names.
This is because if it worked like that you'd have an SQL-injection risk depending on the contents of your parameter.

In order to fix that you'll have to inject your `what_to_show` thingy into the SQL-string.

Like so:

```
var
  what_to_show: string;
begin
  ....
  what_to_show:= 'tables';
  ADOQuery.SQL.Text:= ('SHOW '+what_to_show);
  ....
```

Now it will work.

[image]**Warning**
Make sure test everything you inject into the SQL to prevent users from being able inject their SQL-code into your queries.
Parameters prevent SQL injection, but because you cannot use them here you need to check them against a list of pre-approved values. e.g. a `stringlist` holding all the allowed what_to_shows.
Escaping or use of special chars is useless.

**Safe injection example code**

```
var
  what_to_show: string;
  i: integer;
  inputapproved: boolean;
begin
  ....
  what_to_show:= lower(trim(someinput));
  i:= 0;
  inputapproved:= false;
  while (i < WhiteList.count) and not(inputapproved) do begin
    inputapproved:= ( what_to_show = lower(Whitelist[i]) );
    Inc(i);
  end; {while}
  if inputapproved then ADOQuery.SQL.Text:= ('SHOW '+what_to_show);
  ....
```